# Overcoming xml parameter entity "&" in href in XSLT

Tags: xml

I have just started with xml in the last couple of days and I am playing with XSLT.

I have an html link with the xml parameter entity "&" in it, obviously this stops the files from parsing, is there a simple work around with reverting to other languages?

The link is constructed is this format:

http://www.abc.com/first.php?p=111111111&a=000000&m=1234

I am currently using the basic:

```
                         <xsl:element name="a">
                        <xsl:attribute name="href">
                        <xsl:value-of select="This Is The Link"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="This is The Text Shown"/>
                    </xsl:element>
```

to display the href.

In the example I'm working with I am presuming I am not creating the original xml file.

Apologies for this question, I have searched for a simple answer but much of the related xml texts either don't touch on the issue because it is bad form or lead off into debate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I follow the question. But, if the question is how to get an ampersand in your result tree, then the answer is to escape it. Replace "&" with `"&amp;`". This is valid for URLs as well. If you find a URL with an "&" in it and change it to "`&amp;`" then the URL is processed the same way (i.e., "&" and "`&amp;`" are equivalent).

If I misunderstood your question, then please clarify and I'll try to help!

And for what it's worth, these are the characters that need to be escaped:

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```